# regex select not commented statements

Tags: python, regex

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r(1); echo '</pre>';  <- select this

 echo '<pre>'; print_r($temp); echo '</pre>';  <- select this without space

// echo '<pre>'; print_r($temp); echo '</pre>';  <- skip this



echo '<pre>'; print_r($temp3); echo '</pre>';  <- select this

print_r($temp1);  <- select this

// print_r($temp11);  <- skip this

    print_r($temp2);  <- select this without spaces

    if (true) {
        print_r($temp4);  <- select this without spaces

    }
```

I have a code with print statements I need to select only non commented statements

here is a regex

```
^((?!\/\/\s?))(echo '<pre>';\s?)?(.+)?(print_r)(\.?)(\w+)?\((.+)?\);( echo '<\/pre>';)?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zwUDGI/1)

how to skip spaces ?`'      print_r($temp4);'`
or how can I change regex to make it work ?

Comment: Why all the capture groups ? What and why are you trying to capture ? This is a very simple problem made complex only because it's not clear what you're trying to do. Also, whitespace trimming is as easy as adding `\s*` outside capture groups.

Comment: I'm trying to select "echo '<pre>'; print_r($temp); echo '</pre>';" or print_r($temp2); but not commented

Comment: Still not clear `echo '<pre>'; print_r( //` <- skip this ?  `\n$temp3); echo '</pre>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

rgx = re.compile('^[ \t]*((echo|print_r).*;)', re.MULTILINE)
for line in rgx.finditer(code):
    print line.group(1)

# echo '<pre>'; print_r(1); echo '</pre>';
# echo '<pre>'; print_r($temp); echo '</pre>';
# echo '<pre>'; print_r($temp3); echo '</pre>';
# print_r($temp1);
# print_r($temp2);
# print_r($temp4);
```

Comment: I need to select "echo '<pre>'; print_r($temp); echo '</pre>';" or print_r($temp2); as one selection

Comment: this almost what I need but it didn't select if instead of spaces tab I mean if code indented with tabs it skip selection can you modify regex a little to make it work with tabs too

Comment: Updated. Instead of ``^ *`` at the beginning of the regex, you need ``^[ \t]*``.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this:

```
^(?!\/\/) *(echo '<pre>';\s?)?(.+)?(print_r)(\.?)(\w+)?\((.+)?\);( echo '<\/pre>';)?
```

Comment: this regex also include spaces in full match

Answer (score 0):

This regex wont capture the line if there's a comments `(//, @*, /*, <!--)` otherwise it will capture everything without spaces, hope this will solve your problem.

```
([\n]|^)(?P<group>(?! *\/\/| *@\*| *\/\*| *<!--| *\\\*)([^\n]*?)(\S)(((?! *\/\/| *@\*| *\/\*| *<!--| *\\\*).)*))
```

Comment: @David ty for the tip, I haven't tested it, going to edit now

Comment: isnt that what u wanted?

Comment: if u want I can add to the question the explanation or even make it shorter by excluding the different types of comment, I just think its good to let all types of comments so that u can re-use it

Comment: @David edited just now sir, use the capture group named group if u want the full match of the line :D

Comment: I'm trying to test your regex but it doesn't work can you make it work here https://regex101.com and provide me a link

Comment: yes python, but your example doesn't work it also select empty lines and spaces

Comment: by "doesn't work" u mean it returns error or its not what u need?
btw dont u think it would be better to treat the spaces captured outside the regex? when u include spaces on a negative lookahead it will exclude everything that has spaces on it or it won't capture any spaces at all and concatenate all the characters captured in a line, it can't simply recognize the first character thats a non space and capture from that point

Comment: I need something like this https://regex101.com/r/swrePC/2 without any spaces and empty lines but without commented lines

Answer (score 0):

Here's my interpretation on what you wanted:
[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FToNA2/2)

`"^(?!\s*?//)\s*?(print_r\(.*\);?|echo\s*?'<pre>.*;).*$"gm`

You can get the full explanation on what it does on the side of the web-app